# How can i do automictic Stop the Videos When Play Another Video in laravel site

Tags: javascript, youtube, video-streaming, laravel-8

I'm using YouTube iframe to embed videos on my site developed using php laravel framework. I want to ensure autometic stop others videos when i play one video. I am using following code but not workng it. Can anyone please help me!

```
<iframe id="youtube_player" class="yt_player_iframe" width="100%" height="350" 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{$post->video_link}}" title="YouTube video player" 
 frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
 picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 <script>
  $('.yt_player_iframe').each(function(){
  this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*')
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pause other videos and play the currently clicked one, You have to loop on each one and make sure it is not playing

I have created a sample function and you can workaround it:

```
// Function Argument takes the current player
function pauseOthersYoutubes( currentPlayer ) {
    // Make Sure there is a current video working, if not don't proceed
    if (!currentPlayer) return;
    //Loop to make sure all players are stopped unless the current player
    for (var i = ytplayerList.length; i-- ;){
        if( ytplayerList[i] && (ytplayerList[i] != currentPlayer) ){
            ytplayerList[i].pauseVideo();
        }
    }  
}
```